# Request for Texts Giving an Overview of the Evolution of the Indo-Iranian Laguages

Tags: historical-linguistics, reference-request, comparative-linguistics, indo-aryan

Does anyone know of any good accounts of the evolution of the Modern Indo-Iranian languages?

I'm especially interested in comparative overviews of either the entire family's historical phonology, or within either the Indo-Aryan or Iranic branches, moreso than texts examining a single language.

I'm mostly interested in the evolution from Old Indo-Aryan and Old Iranic onwards, and less-so on the evolution up to that point (from Proto-Indo-Aryan or Proto-Indo-European), but a text covering that too wouldn't be a downside. Changes to Morphology and Syntax are also of a lower priority to me than sound change.